# Code Review Tool for CollabNet SVN Edge

Tags: windows, svn, pre-commit-hook, collabnet, post-commit-hook

I'm using [CollabNet Subversion Edge](http://www.open.collab.net/products/subversion/) server on Windows to manage our code repositories and I really like the simple administration.

What I am looking for is something open-source/free that would easily integrate with [CollabNet's Subversion Edge](http://www.open.collab.net/products/subversion/) to offer some form of web-based code review and specific instructions on how to get it up and running.

We are open to both pre-commit and post-commit review, but likely will want to work with post-commit review to start, so instructions on how to setup the appropriate hooks for windows would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I think, *best choice* (and **not easiest**) will be [Review Board](http://www.reviewboard.org/), but you can try hosted [RBCommons](https://www.rbcommons.com/)
- [Rietveld](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/rietveld.html) have some rights to be mentioned
- [Codestriker](http://codestriker.sourceforge.net/index.html) (but it's Perl,no updates from 2009-11)
- [Java Code Reviewer](http://jcodereview.sourceforge.net/)
- [AgileReview](http://www.agilereview.org/) (beware - Eclipse)

Non-free, closed, costly, but **"The Right Thing"**

- [Atlassian Cruicible](http://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible/overview)
- [SmartBear CodeCollaborator|CodeReview](http://smartbear.com/products/software-development/code-review)